# List index giving wrong value?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, finance

```
import stockquotes
 

symbol_name = ['SPY', 'XOM', 'GLD']
for x in symbol_name:
    ticker = stockquotes.Stock(x)
    today_price = ticker.current_price
    print(x, 'Quote: ',today_price)
```

Output:

```
SPY Quote:  337.13
XOM Quote:  41.96
GLD Quote:  182.24
```

But when I try to get XOM's quote through the list's index I get GLD's quote instead.

```
print(symbol_name[1], today_price)
```

Output:

```
XOM 182.24
```

***Any thoughts on how I can access each quote manually?***

Comment: You're overwriting `today_price` each time through the loop. When the loop is done it has the last price.

Comment: `today_price` is not a list, you're not indexing it.

Comment: Do you understand how variables work? Why do you think the value of `today_price` would change depending on what index of `symbol_name` you're printing?

Comment: Make a dictionary that maps ticker symbols to prices.

Comment: Dictionary! Gotcha thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the prices in a dictionary. Then access by the `symbol name`.

```
import stockquotes
 

symbol_name = ['SPY', 'XOM', 'GLD']
data = {}
for x in symbol_name:
    ticker = stockquotes.Stock(x)
    today_price = ticker.current_price
    data[x] = today_price

print(data['XOM'])
```

Output:

```
41.96
```